# Why my soql query is returning 'RecordTypeId' instead of the fields mentioned in the query?

Tags: soql, subquery

Why my soql query is returning 'RecordTypeId' instead of the fields mentioned in the query?

Here's my query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, ABC, (SELECT Id, XYZ FROM InnerObject) FROM OuterObj
```

Note: My query contains a subquery.

Comment: Please post your query.

Comment: SELECT Id, Name, ABC, (SELECT Id, XYZ FROM InnerObject) FROM OuterObj

Comment: What do you mean by returning 'RecordTypeId'?

Comment: When I run the same query in developer console I am getting the result as expected, but when I run the query in apex class using Database.query() method I am getting the Id field Name field and a RecordTypeId.

Comment: Please post your whole code. It's really difficult to help without it and with 
a pseudo code query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using System.debug, this is expected. SObject's default "toString" method doesn't show subqueries. If you're interested in seeing that data, you need to debug the subquery instead:

```
OuterObj[] outerObjList = [SELECT Name, (SELECT XYZ FROM InnerObject) FROM OuterObj];
for(OuterObj record: outerObjList) {
  System.debug(record.InnerObject);
}
```

RecordTypeId is a field *automatically* appended to your query by the SOQL engine in Apex Code. This is done so that Visualforce can automatically determine which picklist values are available for a given picklist field.